# On datepicker calendar how to set date to property 'minDate' without disabling previous months

Tags: datepicker, mindate

I want to set `minDate` on Date to calendar `#dateto` without disabling previous months.

By default the calendar `#datefrom` and `#dateto` have set property `minDate` to `today`

Take for example that the `today` date `2019-2-8`

The goal is to select the date `2019-5-15` from the '#datefrom' calendar and set this date in the `#dateto` calendar as `minDate`, and the calendars `#dateto` will be set to `2019-5 -15` as `minDate` and I want to move normally to month 2, now I can not because I was blocked in previous months.

Date from

```
  $('#datefrom').datepicker({
           stepMonths: 1,
           numberOfMonths: 2,
           minDate : 'today',
           dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
           showOtherMonths: true,
           onSelect: function(date){
             $('.datefrom-text').text(date);
             $('#dateto').datepicker('option', 'minDate', date);
           }
        });
```

Date to

```
$('#dateto').datepicker({
 stepMonths: 1,
 numberOfMonths: 2,
 minDate : 'today',
 dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
 showOtherMonths: true,
 onSelect: function(date){
  $('.dateto-text').text(date);
 }
});
```

**[Here is my jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/smilohanic/zavqr9fL/)**

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: Hi @NicoHaase, as title reads, I want to set minDate on the second calendar but I need to be able to see previous months (not available but visible). Check jsfiddle example it will be clear, slelect May 1 on first calendar, then I want to be able to see months Feb/Mar/Apr in second calendar when minDate is set. Thanks

Comment: Please edit your question to contain all information. Additionally, explain what works yet and where you are currently struggling to get forward

Comment: @NicoHaase ok I corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to move calendars by calling internal datepicker method, so I hope it will help you to get what you need. [Check my jsfiddle fork](https://jsfiddle.net/davorpeic/gz6mo8bq/11/)

```
$.datepicker._selectMonthYear( '#dateto', document.getElementById("fakeMonthSelected"), "M" );
```

Davor

Answer (score 1):

You could probably use beforeShowDay
http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-beforeShowDay
It gets called for every date before it's shown on screen. 
You could define a function that would manually check if the date was selectable (date > minDate) and return that from the function.
Haven't tried it, but I believe it should work.